# C++ program to make registry through WMI entry is not working.

Tags: c++, registry, wmi

I have edited the code below to make a registry entry using WMI invoking through c++ but though the code is returning zero it is not making registry entry. I have run it with admin privileges. But the code for reading reg entry is perfectly working. Hope that somebody will help me with this.

```
    void cppMain()
    {
    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------
    ComLibUsage     comLibUsage( ComLibUsage::Threading::multiThreaded );

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------
    // Note: If you are using Windows 2000, you must specify -
    // the default authentication credentials for a user by using
    // a SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_LIST structure in the pAuthList ----
    // parameter of CoInitializeSecurity ------------------------
    CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL) || Fail( "Failed to initialize security" );

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------
    IWbemLocatorPtr     pLoc;
    CoCreateInstance( CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc) || Fail( "Failed to create IWbemLocator object." );

    // Step 4: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method
    // Connect to the local root\cimv2 namespace
    // and obtain pointer pSvc to make IWbemServices calls.
    IWbemServicesPtr    pSvc;
    pLoc->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\default"), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, &pSvc ) || Fail( "Could not connect." );
    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\default WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels for the proxy ------------------------
    CoSetProxyBlanket( pSvc, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE) || Fail( "Could not set proxy blanket" );

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // set up to call the WmiSetBrightness Method
    _bstr_t     methodName  = L"CreateKey";
    _bstr_t     className   = L"StdRegProv";

    IWbemClassObjectPtr pClass;
    pSvc->GetObject(className, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL)
        || Fail( "GetObject(className, ...) failed" );

    IWbemClassObjectPtr pInParamsDefinition;
    pClass->GetMethod(methodName, 0, &pInParamsDefinition, NULL)
        || Fail( "GetMethod(methodName, ...) failed" );

    IWbemClassObjectPtr pClassInstance;
    pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance)
        || Fail( "SpawnInstance failed" );

    _variant_t  var1( L"2147483650" );
    pClassInstance->Put(L"hDefKey", 0, &var1, CIM_UINT32)|| Fail( "Put failed for 'hDefKey'" );


    _variant_t  var2( L"SOFTWARE\\Newkey" );
    pClassInstance->Put(L"sSubKeyName", 0, &var2, CIM_STRING)|| Fail( "Put failed for 'sSubKeyName'" );


    /*_variant_t  var3( L"CachePrefix" );
    pClassInstance->Put(L"sValueName", 0, &var3, CIM_STRING)|| Fail( "Put failed for 'sValueName'" );

    _variant_t  var4( L"CachePrefix" );
    pClassInstance->Put(L"sValue", 0, &var4, CIM_STRING)|| Fail( "Put failed for 'sValue'" );*/

    // Execute Method
    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
     pSvc->ExecMethod(className, methodName, 0,
    NULL, pClassInstance, &pOutParams, NULL)|| Fail( "Could not execute method" );

    // To see what the method returned,
    // use the following code.  The return value will
    // be in &varReturnValue

    _variant_t varReturnValue;
    pOutParams->Get(_bstr_t(L"ReturnValue"), 0, &varReturnValue, NULL, 0)|| Fail( "Get failed" );
    wcout << varReturnValue.intVal << endl;
    //std::wstring result = varReturnValue.bstrVal;
    //wcout << result;

    system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: You are not checking any return values for errors. Do that first. Also, I am pretty sure there are easier ways to manipulate registry than using WMI.

Comment: Return value is 0 which i suppose is success

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this problem is the same as mine but I was facing a similar issue a while back and decided to circle back my findings for anyone stumbling across this post.

I was working on very similar code. In my case, I was working with x86. Somehow during testing, I switched to x64 and the code started working. That gave me a starting point and I eventually figured out that we need to set the context of the provider and required architectures. Here are some links that I found useful: [Setting context for architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/getting-and-providing-data-on-a-64-bit-computer).